# Save Query in MySql Trigger

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I want to save the mysql query used to delete a row in a table:

Example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `table_DEL` BEFORE DELETE ON `table`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
INSERT INTO db_bk.table
SELECT *,NOW(),QUERY()
FROM db.table
WHERE table_id= OLD.table_id; 
END
```

As you understand, I want to now if exists a query() function or another method to retrieve the query that activate the trigger (the exact delete query)

Thank you very much

Comment: There is no such function, but you can find this query in General Query Log - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-logs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @devart said - such a function doesn't exist. If you are worried about who will delete from your table then restrict the 'delete' permission to one account. Then you can control how records are removed and when.